# Load AdView with Admob Android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob, google-play-services

How can i load an AdView in Android (Eclipse). i tried everything without results!
i add google play services lib in the project, i try to follow some manual, documentation but nothing show me the ad..
this is my code!
Thanks

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.carle.segretihs"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >



    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".SecretsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_secrets" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
</application>

 </manifest>
```

SecretsActivity.java

```
public class SecretsActivity extends FragmentActivity  {
ImageView a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,l;
private InterstitialAd interstitial;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_secrets);


    int eroe=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("eroe");

    a=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    b=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    c=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    d=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    e=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
    f=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
    g=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
    h=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
    i=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
    l=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView10);

    AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID")
    .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    //other code


}
}
```

activity_secrets.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/hearthtexture"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}"
android:id="@+id/rootViewGroup"
 >

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-2830551115211229/5191182799" >
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show the code where you actually do the ad request pls

Comment: do it! it's before "//other code"

Comment: What do you see in the logcat related to the Ad?

Comment: 11-28 20:53:51.739: E/AndroidRuntime(10373): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.carle.segretihs/com.carle.segretihs.SecretsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 6171000 but found 5089000.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Comment: seems your using an older version of google play services, did you update to the latest using the sdk manager?

Comment: it's all update in SDK manager..

Answer (score 0):

try putting com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView below the Scrollview in the xml. If the scrollview is larger then the screen, the adview will be hidden underneath it.

Comment: the app crashes when i insert the instructions for load the request of AdView.. is not a layout problem..